# removing outlier using IQR is giving error 'No axis named 1 for object type Series'

Tags: python, pandas

while removing outliers using IQR from a column, it is showing me the error - 'No axis named 1 for object type Series'

```
df = df[~((df['DISTANCE_FROM_HOME'] < (q1 - 1.5 * iqr)) 
          |(df['DISTANCE_FROM_HOME'] > (q3 + 1.5 * iqr))
          ).any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: Just remove `.any(axis=1)`. You already have binary or: `|`

Comment: thanks Quang..it worked